# Limit in integral: $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac1{\epsilon}\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f(s)ds=f(t)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth function  :

can someone tell me why we have :

$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f(s)ds=f(t)$

thank you very much !

Comment: You should recognize the left hand side as the derivative of something.

Comment: what is your definition for $\int_a^b f(s) ds$ ? mine is $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(a+n (b-a)/N)$ so that the result of your limit is $f(t)$ is not complicated (on $[a;b]$, $f(s)$ has a minimum and a maximum and it is bounded by those, when $b \to a$ these bounds converge to $f(a)$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac1\epsilon \int_t^{t+\epsilon}f(s)\,ds-f(t)\right|&\le\frac1\epsilon \int_t^{t+\epsilon}\left|f(s)-f(t)\right|\,ds\\\\
&\le \sup_{s\in[t,t+\epsilon]}\left|f(s)-f(t)\right|\\\\
&\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,\epsilon \to 0
\end{align}$$

since $f(s)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[t,t+\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(x) = \int_0^x f$. Then $F$ is smooth since $f$ is, and $F^\prime = f$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus; but we also have $$F^\prime(t) = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{F(t+\varepsilon) - F(t)}{\varepsilon} = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{\int_t^{t+\varepsilon} f}{\varepsilon}.$$