# Prove $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{(t,t+\epsilon)}pd\lambda=p(t)$, $p$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

If $\mu$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R}_+, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+))$ such that $\mu([0,t])$ is finite for all $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$, where $\mathbb{R}_+=[0,+\infty)$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ is Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}_+$. $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}_+$. $\mu\ll\lambda$.

I need to show the following limit at $\lambda$-almost every $t$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$:

$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{(t,t+\epsilon]}pd\lambda=p(t)$,

where $p$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\mu/d\lambda$.

The equation is familiar to me in calculus, but here, as a Radon-Nikodym derivative, all I know about $p$ is that it is positive measurable, not a bounded real-valued one in the definition of Riemann integral, so the tools I have in calculus cannot be applied (a similar thread is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639492/limit-in-integral-lim-limits-epsilon-rightarrow-0-frac1-epsilon-int-t), but it's all calculus). From the condition that $\mu([0,t])$ is finite, I have a feeling that $p$ is smooth enough to make the limit hold, but I don't know specifically what attribute of a Radon-Nikodym derivative can be used to prove this limit.   Can you please give me some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: I see. Thank you. Never heard about it in Rudin's Real and complex analysis. Do you know what good textbook contains this theorem?

Comment: In Rudin's RCA see the theorem just before the section on 'Metric Density'.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Thank you, but I did not find the section on 'Metric Density'. The only appearance of this is in exercise 11 of Chapter 8 "Differentiation". Is the Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem somewhere in this chapter? If so, I will take some time to search for it.

Comment: May be we have different editions of the book. The theorem is in the chapter on differrentiation.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Thank you.